# Getting the error ""exec: \"python2\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown." when trying to run container interactively

Tags: python-2.7, docker

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
# Use Python base image from DockerHub 
FROM python:2.7 

WORKDIR /salmon

# INSTALL CMAKE
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo \
    && sudo apt-get update \
    && sudo apt-get install -y \
    python \
    cmake \
    wget 

#INSTALL BOOST
RUN wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.66.0/source/boost_1_66_0.tar.gz \
    && mv boost_1_66_0.tar.gz /usr/local/bin/ \
    && cd /usr/local/bin/ \
    && tar -xzf boost_1_66_0.tar.gz \
    && cd ./boost_1_66_0/ \
    && ./bootstrap.sh \
    && ./b2 install

#INSTALL SALMON
RUN wget https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/salmon/releases/download/v0.14.1/salmon-0.14.1_linux_x86_64.tar.gz \
    && mv salmon-0.14.1_linux_x86_64.tar.gz /usr/local/bin/ \
    && cd /usr/local/bin/ \
    && tar -xzf salmon-0.14.1_linux_x86_64.tar.gz \
    && cd salmon-latest_linux_x86_64/ 

ENV PATH=/salmon/

ADD . /salmon
```

When I try to run it interactively via `sudo docker run -v ~/Documents/Docker/salmon_test/:/data -it salmon:00.00.01`, I get the error:

```
"exec: \"python2\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown."
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I even added the `sudo apt-get install python` command (which I didn't have before) but that didn't solve this either. Any thoughts?

Comment: `ENV PATH=/salmon/` overrides the default PATH variable... so it won't search for python2 in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of overriding the `$PATH` variable and as a result, the container failed to find executable.

Default PATH value is

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

So when you set this to `/salmon/` you can then call python using full path like `/usr/local/bin/python`, btw you should not update PATH variable like this.

Better to update with the existing PATH variable.

```
FROM python:2.7 
ENV PATH="/salmon/:${PATH}"
.
.
```